# Why is the sky blue? Due to the ozone layer or due to ''light scatterization in atmosphere''?

Tags: atmosphere, ozone, light

I've found several answers to the question of why the sky is blue.
Basically the title. Elaborate however you want...

Comment: if you google this you get 1,6 billion hits,what more do you want?

Comment: In short: the scattering of light. Ozone offers some protections against UV light.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to insufficient research.

Comment: I think the reason for the question is that Google gives some wrong results (Ozone layer) as well as the right one. It's clearly earth science, and I encourage somebody to put time into a good canonical answer.

Comment: Answered at https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/is-the-color-of-the-sky-the-same-everywhere-on-earth/3068

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate - it just happens to share an answer with a different question. I think this site should have a "Why is the sky blue?" question with a good answer, and I'm hoping somebody will write one (I might take a shot in a day or two when I have time, if there's nothing by then)